# Adding data into tuples of create columns in tables php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to add data into tuples of the columns create in the tables of a database. The form is dynamic adding numerous input fields when required by the user.
The database is created from one input field.

The tables are created from other input fields

The columns are created from one input box and split to create the columns linking to the tables.

Now I am trying to add data into the columns created

```
$dbConnectionT = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbName);

$counter = 0;
// create loop to assign input boxes together
foreach($combined as $message => $answer)
{
    // replace the white space from input box to database data type and data length
    $columns = "`".str_replace(" ", "` TEXT(60), `", $answer)."` TEXT(60)"; 
    // create the tables and columns from the message text box
    $sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE " . $message . "( " . $columns . " )";

    echo "</br>";   

    $counter ++;                    
    // if the connection and sql query is true echo for debugging   
    if ($dbConnectionT->query($sqlCreateTable) == TRUE) 
    {
        echo "{$message} = {$answer}";
        echo "</br>";
        echo "Message " . $counter . " is sent ";

        echo "</br>";
    }
}
```

So I am trying to add an input form in the php next to the columns of the tables, which is answer! So i can add data into them tuples.
Please note I understand this is bad database work, although this is not going live and just learning PHP.
Thanks in advance

This is the output I get

```
Database one was created

RFq = Id item price
Message 1 is sent

quote = qid item price
Message 2 is sent
```

And I would like a text box next to the "Id Item Price" to be able to insert into them columns of the database

Comment: whats your actual error ?

Comment: I havent got an error, just trying to add data into the tuples of the columns create in the tables, and just a bit unsure of how to go about it, i have been trying all sorts